# Sweeting and Bottling a cider/cyser

Tags: carbonation, cider

I fermented 5 gallons of cider from 1.044 to 1.0. It's very tart, so I want to add 2 lbs of honey to sweeten it up.

I also want to bottle it with some carbonation. How do I prevent the honey from fermenting it back down to 1.0 and still sweeten the cyser?

I looked at carbonation tablets, but they just appear to be modified sugar cubes.
If I stop the fermentation with Campden, can I still bottle carb it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in HB Forum. http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showthread.php?t=447120

Rack to a fresh carboy leaving all the settled out yeast and sediment behind.

Add:

1/2 tsp potassium sorbate per gallon.
1/4 - 1/2 tsp TOTAL potassium metabisulfite for the batch.

Add and stir gently. Give the cider 4-7 days.

Then rack to a fresh carboy and sweeten. If planning on kegging/force carbing, you can rack to the keg instead of a carboy.

This my proven method for Sussreserve.

As to how much to sweeten, that is very subjective. You should pull a sample, taste, and add sweetener slowly to your desired level. Then scale up for the entire batch.

I sweeten with more cider, usually in a ratio close to 1:5 or 1:6 (1 gal cider to 5 gal hard cider).

Its very easy to make a sweet cider... OR a carbonated cider. But a bit tricky to make one that is BOTH. To do that you must sweeten, then artificially carb (force carb), or sweeten with something non-fermentable (like splenda or xylitol), and bottle carb with priming sugar.

Answer (score -1):

If you stop the fermentation with camden, you will not be able to bottle carb it. The camden will prevent the yeast from functioning in the bottles.

You can add the honey, bottle immediately, and once they have carbonated, store the bottles in a cold environment (mid to high 30's) to force the yeast into hibernation. This will allow the yeast to carbonate the bottles, but stop them from eating all the sugar and blowing the bottles apart.

Comment: Campden alone will not stop the yeast from fermenting residual sugar -- it just knocks them back a bit. You need to add potassium sorbate *and* campden in the correct amounts. You can use Google to find the quantities.

Comment: As, @TobiasPatton said, Campden alone will not stop the fermentation. Also, while cooling the bottles will cause the yeast to hibernate, it will *not* prevent them from starting back up later if the bottles are allowed to come back up in temperature, and therefore does not remove the risk of bottle bombs. The safest and most reliable way to carbonate sweetened ciders is to stabilize, keg, and force carbonate.